# How to show the solution is unique to ODE given initial value?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am new to the ODE concepts, and I am a bit confused how to prove a seemingly simple question:

If $x'=kx$, where $x(0)=5$ and $k=-10$, why is $x(t)=5e^{-10t}$ the unique solution under such condition?

Comment: You should look at the cauchy theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Assume another "solution" exists and call it $y(t)$. Then $y(0) = 5, y' = ky$.Thus $(y-x)(t)' = y'-x' = k(y-x) = -10(y-x) \Rightarrow y-x = Ce^{-10t}$.But $(y-x)(0) = y(0) - x(0) = 5 - 5 = 0 \Rightarrow C = 0 \Rightarrow y - x = 0 \Rightarrow y = x$.